# How to detect IP conflict using cisco LMS?

Tags: cisco, ip

Can anybody help me how to identify if there is any IP conflict within my network using **Cisco LMS**?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally an IP address conflict is logged. Do "show log". You will see something like ***`Duplicate address 10.25.32.15 on Vlan25 sourced by 0011.2233.4455 and there will be another message with the other mac address`***. so easly you can log those message in your LMS server. as you know LMS has a day 1 syslog support out of the box. Means as soon as LMS is installed, it is ready to serve you as a Syslog Server. Though it may not have so many features like other dedicated syslog Server, but it has important syslog related features, being syslog is among one of the hundreds of things LMS does.

All you have to do to make syslog work is to ***`Subscribe Syslog Collector on the server from Admin > Collection Settings > Syslog and configure device to send syslog to LMS Server`***. Then all you have to do is to Generate Syslog Report from LMS GUI.
othere methodes to define the ip conflict can be found in [this link](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13563/identifying-an-ip-address-conflict-through-a-cisco-switch)

Comment: Exactly, duplicate ip is logged aka syslog. I don't know what level syslog it is but you could easily figure it out. Simply setup the networking device to syslog that to your LMS server. Then configure your LMS server to do something special when it gets that. Also see EEM, you could have an email sent to you (this is outside of LMS though)